# The structure of the embedded submanifold.

Tags: manifolds, examples-counterexamples, submanifold

If $M$ is a manifold and $S$ is an embedded submanifold, I wanted to understand with which structure we should endow the embedded submanifold. So I was reading [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Embedded_submanifolds.). The structure they define is not exactly the first that that came to my mind. Intuitively I would have chosen the structure $\{(U\cap S, \phi_{U\cap S}) : (U,\phi) \text{ is a chart for }$M$\}$. Can someone provide me a simple example why this doesn't work?

Comment: $U \cap S$ is not necessarily homeomorphic to an open ball. As an example, take $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its single chart and $S^2$ as an embedded submanifold. Since you need at least $2$ charts to cover $S^2$, you can see it doesn't work here and can see what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot (in general) obtain an atlas for a (embedded) submanifold $S \subset M$ by simply restricting an atlas on the ambient manifold $M$. This is because (topological) manifolds are comprised of more than just pure topological data (they are more than just subspaces); they require the data of a topology *and* (at least) the data of charts. Since charts involve functions with specific properties, they *aren't* inherited in the same way the open sets are. Recall that an atlas of charts on $S$ is: for every point $p \in S$ an open subset $U \ni p$ equipped with a homeomorphism to an open subset of some $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Of course, the typical counterexample to direct inheritance of charts to topological subspaces is $S = \mathbb{S}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1} = M$ where $M$ has the single chart $(M,\mathbf{id})$ and $S$ has the subspace topology. Restriction of the identity map $\mathbf{id}:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ to $S$ doesn't produce a homeomorphism onto an **open** subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ for any $k$.

The obstruction? Restriction of charts isn't sufficiently local (and the nature of manifolds is that they are global objects patched together from *local* data) because of the homeomorphism to an open set condition.

The fix? Since $S$ is known to be a submanifold, then for each $p \in S$ you should find a chart $(U,\phi)$ from the *maximal* atlas of $M$ such that $(U \cap S, \phi|_{U \cap S})$ is a chart on $S$. This approach respects the local data on $S$ by importing local, not global, data from $M$. [As it turns out, by the rank theorem you can guarantee that these charts are "slice charts" (cf. the intrinsic structure of a submanifold you see on your wiki link)]

In the example above with $n=1$, if $S$ is the unit circle in $M=\mathbb{R}^2$, and $p=(0,1)$, then you can take the chart $(U,\phi)$ of $M$, where $U = \{y < 1\}$ and $\phi(x,y) = (\frac{x}{1-y}, 1-x^2-y^2)$. Then $(U \cap S, \phi|_{U \cap S})$ is a chart on $S$ (a slice chart, in fact, since it maps to $\mathbb{R} \times {0}$).

The moral? Submanifolds *do* inherit their structures from the manifold data of the ambient space (as you believed), but you have to dig around inside of $M$'s maximal atlas to restrict an appropriate set of charts. Moreover, if $S$ is any subspace such that every point $p \in S$ is contained in a chart of $M$ that restricts to a slice chart